# Location of strong name key file in window 10

Tags: windows-10

Where can I find my newly created strong name key file for Visual Studio 2012? I think it is somewhere in program files(x86)...assemblies.. but not sure where it precisely is.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It is in C:\Windows\System32 .